# Windows batch: killing processes

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have several processes running which have the same name. I want to have an option to kill them from a batch script. I need something very similar to unix shell command:

```
kill -9 `ps -axuw | grep MY_PROCESS_NAME | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `taskkill`.

`taskkill /im MY_PROCESS_NAME /f`

That will kill all processes under the name you specify i.e. `iexplore.exe`

Type `taskkill /?` at a cmd prompt for all the options.